# grails abstract domain classes : quick easy way to scaffold so the list view of domains link correctly

Tags: grails, abstract-class

I am working on an Grails app where a handful of Children domain classes extend a base abstract domain class.  I also have a Parent domain class that has many of the abstract domain class.  When you run "grails generate-all" for the Parent and then create a parent with a bunch of Children, the links in the list view point to the abstract domain class which doesnt have a controller or views.  What would be the easiest way to get this view to work?  If question is a bit fuzzy, below is some pseudo code to help make things clearer.

The Domain Classes

```
abstract class Automobile{
    String description
}

class Car extends Automobile{}

class Truck extends Automobile{}

class Dealership{
   static hasMany = [automobiles:Automobile]
}
```

Creating a Dealership with a Car and a Truck

```
def car = new Car(description:"Toyota Camry").save()
def truck = new Truck(description : "Toyota Tacoma").save()

def dealership = new Dealership()
dealership.addToAutomobiles(car)
dealership.addToAutomobiles(truck)
dealership.save()
```

The generated show.gsp for Dealership will look something like this :

```
<htm>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <td>${dealershipInstance.id}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Automobiles</th>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <g:each in="${dealershipInstance.automobiles}" status="i" var="automobileInstance">
          <li><g:link action="show" id="${automobileInstance.id}">${automobileInstance.description}</g:link></li>
        </g:each>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

The problem lies in the link to the automobile instance as the base abstract class Automobile does not have a view of its own.  So the "Show" action returns a 404.  What would be the best way to link to the appropriate domain class in this case?  There is probably an easy way to address this, I just haven't found it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid writing groovy or java code within my gsp I added a string variable with the classname for easy reference within the gsp.

```
<g:link controller="${p.classname}" action="show" id="${p.id}">${p.description} ${p?.classname}</g:link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks croteau. Your question and answer lead me to a solution similar to yours. You don't have to add a classname property to your Domain class though. It is already there.

Use the class.simpleName to get what you need instead.

For example:

```
<g:link controller="${p.class.simpleName}" action="show" id="${p.id}">${p.description}</g:link>
```